# How to render el-dialog before the first popup?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

If the el-dialog has not opened before,elements under el-dialog cannot be retrieved using `this.$refs` as elements has not rendered.
I want to know how to render el-dialog but not show it because I need to initialize something in el-dialog.

Comment: How are you toggling it? Are you using `v-if` or is the functionality built-in?

Comment: Try `@open` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vm.$nextTick( [callback] )`

Example

in methods

```
OpenDialog() {

this.dialogFormVisible = true; // your dialog toggle variable

    this.$nextTick(() => {
     
     // some action or your this.$refs will here
    
    });
},
```

Reference
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick